# Segmentation fault when I try to separe a char* into tokens

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, strtok

I'm working at a homework in C++ and I am not allowen to include `<sstream>`.
I'm trying to tokenize a char* like this:

```
char *p;
p = strtok(New_string, " ");
while (p) {
    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    std::cout << strlen(p);
}
```

My problem is that `std::cout << strlen(p);` causes a SEG FAULT.
Could somebody offer an alternative to strtok() or a solution for accessing everytime strlen(p)?

Comment: Why not just check for NULL pointer returned by `strtok` before calling `strlen` with it? `strtok` returns NULL when the end of string is reached as far as I recall so you should be checking anyway

Comment: Yes, it is null terminated.

Comment: And `New_string` is.......?

Answer (score 2):

You are checking that `p` is not null in your `while` conditional, but you reset it with the return value from `strtok`

```
while (p) {
    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    std::cout << strlen(p);
}
```

Now there is no guarantee that `p` is not NULL any longer. You should check again that it is not null before passing it to `strlen`. When the end of string is reached, `strtok` will return a null pointer (similarly if no token is found), so the check is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

`strtok` will return `NULL` when no more tokens are found.  Because of that, I think this is what you want:

```
char *p;
p = strtok(New_string, " ");
while (p) {
    std::cout << strlen(p);
    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

Note that the `std::cout <<...` and `strtok` have been swapped.